# Wrapping my head around windows.h - const char* vs LPSTR

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am getting started with the following simple messagebox application. The problem is that when I run this application the text is Chinese. I clearly have an encoding issue. Can someone point me to somewhere I can learn about windows.h specific string typedefs?

//test.c

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello World", "Note", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you've got `UNICODE` defined, as your comment to Laserallan's answer suggests, this shouldn't ever have compiled.  You should have gotten an error related to conversion of `const char*` to `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: My guess is that it may be a .c file rather than a .cpp file and the c compiler is somewhat more liberal when it comes to type error.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that. This is a .c file

Comment: Write a L in front of your constant strings e.g. L"Hello World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a wide char vs ordinary char issue. Try changing the code to:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello World", L"Note", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

If this solves your problem it means your project is configured for wide characters rather than ordinary chars. Adding an L in front of a string constant will make it a wide char constant. This is generally a good thing since it's way easier to manage internationalization for a wide char application.

These web pages covers the Windows API and unicode in more detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This still isn't exactly right, an application built for `UNICODE=1` should use `wWinMain`.

Answer (score 3):

When using the windows API (almost) every declaration with null-terminated strings uses `TCHAR` ,`LPTSTR` and `LPCTSTR` which are define as `char` ,`char*` and `const char*` when you're **not** building with UNICODE as character-set
and are defined as `wchar_t` ,`wchar_t*` and `const wchar_t*` when you are building with the UNICODE character-set.

Also the `UNICODE` and/or `_UNICODE` definition(s) controll which function is being compiled when you call an windows-API function. Almost every function has two versions ,one for UNICODE and one for non-UNICODE.

for instance MessageBox is either translated to MessageBoxA (non-UNOCODE version) or MessageBoxW (UNOCDE-version).

Further more :

```
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance ,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance ,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) 
{
// ...
}
```

is often defined as :

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance ,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance ,LPTSTR lpCmdLine ,int nCmdShow ) 
{
// ...
}
```

for the last version you need to include `<tchar.h>` which has the right translation for _`tWinMain` (or _`tmain` when building consle-app).

Hope this clarefies things for you.

Comment: Looks like VS sets this project to build with character types set to Unicode by default. Should I leave this and just prefix my string literals with L?

Comment: You can use the _T( ... ) macro that puts the L there for you when building for UNICODE. Whether one should use UNICODE is another question ,which i can't answer for sure (I use it but don't really know why.

Comment: @Nick, if you know for certain that you'll never need to compile for multibyte characters, then using `L` and the `W` versions of the API functions is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: As long as you are certain on that side it's fine with me. People certain not to use multibyte characters tend to be

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Hello World"), _T("Note"), MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is most likely that you are building a UNICODE application and are passing pointers to char strings when the API wants pointers to wchar_t strings

Comment: This still isn't quite right, source code meant to compile for either MBCS or Unicode should use `_tWinMain`.

Comment: True. I used the _T() macro instead of L"" because he'd be far more likely to encounter _T than L in Microsoft generated code.